# Send Message over Socket to a Server when Button is clicked on a Fragment

Tags: java, android, sockets, android-fragments, android-asynctask

I can already receive multiple messages from a server using an `AsyncTask`, and I also know how to send.

I don't know how I can send the message when I get a button interruption/pulling from multiple fragments.

I have 1 button on Fragment A and 1 Button on Fragment B.

Fragment A

```
public class Fragmento_A extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{

    Button button;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_third,container,false);

        button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);

        new Cliente("192.168.2.5",6000,button,Fragment_B.button).execute();

        return v;
    }
}
```

Fragment B

```
public class Fragmento_B extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment{

    public static Button button;
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_third,container,false);

        button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);

        return v;
    }
}
```

AsyncTask

```
public class Cliente extends AsyncTask<Void, String, Void> {

    String dstAddress;
    int dstPort;
    Button button,button2

    public Cliente(String addr, int port, Button button, Button button2) {

    this.button = button;
    this.button2 = button2;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                socket = new Socket(dstAddress, dstPort);
                while(true) {

                     //what to do here?
                }

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

            } finally {
                if (socket != null) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {}
```

When a button is clicked on Fragment_A,  it should send: Button_A pressed (only execute once) and when a button is clicked on Fragment_B it should send: Button_B pressed (also only executed once).

Or maybe the easiest way is to send always the state of the button to the server and the server handles when he gets a determined string/int...

Answer (score 0):

An easy (but maybe not that beautiful) solution would be to use a blocking queue. In your main thread where the AsyncTask is spawned create a `BlockingQueue` and make it `final`. Then write a note into the queue when the button is pressed (you could write a string to the queue which contains the data you want to send) and in the AsyncTask create a loop that reads elements out of the queue and sends their content.

[BlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)

Hope that helps.

Comment: That might work although I think there are easier solutions. Let's see if someone else replies.

Comment: Why not just create a public static string? Isnt it the same?

Comment: No, thats not the same. It would work theoratically but it's not thrad safe. Your app could crash unexpectedly without any apparent reason. This happens when two threads try to access the same memory address at the same time. That's why you block threads. The BlockingQueue blocks the second thread until the first writes to it so that problem won't occur with BlockingQueue.

Comment: Also, a queue is better than a string in situations when the user presses the button twice while the AsyncThread works on the first request.